# Why does HashMap have iter_mut() but HashSet doesn't?

Tags: rust, standard-library, idioms

What is the design rationale for supplying an `iter_mut` function for [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter_mut) but not [`HashSet`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) in Rust?

Would it be a faux pas to roll one's own (assuming that can even be done)?

Having one could alleviate situations that give rise to

> previous borrow of `X` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents 
>   subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `X` until the borrow ends

## Example

[An extremely convoluted example (Gist)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=be2ab19dda2d479dc715&version=stable) that does not show-case why the parameter passing is the way that it is. Has a short comment explaining the pain-point:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn derp(v: i32, unprocessed: &mut HashSet<i32>) {
    if unprocessed.contains(&v) {

        // Pretend that v has been processed
        unprocessed.remove(&v);
    }   
}

fn herp(v: i32) {
    let mut unprocessed: HashSet<i32> = HashSet::new();
    unprocessed.insert(v);

    // I need to iterate over the unprocessed values
    while let Some(u) = unprocessed.iter().next() {

        // And them pass them mutably to another function
        // as I will process the values inside derp and
        // remove them from the set.
        //
        // This is an extremely convoluted example but
        // I need for derp to be a separate function
        // as I will employ recursion there, as it is
        // much more succinct than an iterative version.
        derp(*u, &mut unprocessed);
    }   
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    herp(10);
}
```

The statement

```
while let Some(u) = unprocessed.iter().next() {
```

is an immutable borrow, hence

```
derp(*u, &mut unprocessed);
```

is impossible as unprocessed cannot be borrowed mutably. The immutable borrow does not end until the end of the while-loop.

I have tried to use [this as reference](http://blog.ezyang.com/2013/12/two-bugs-in-the-borrow-checker-every-rust-developer-should-know-about/) and essentially ended up with trying to fool the borrow checker through various permutations of assignments, enclosing braces, but due to the coupling of the intended expressions the problem remains.

Comment: Note that `while let Some(u) = unprocessed.iter().next()` is equivalent to `for u in &unprocessed`

Comment: You have another issue here: you cannot borrow `unprocessed` mutably while iterating over it/holding references into it. Why not simply have the loop *consume* `unprocessed` and simplify your program logic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `HashSet` contains a `Copy` type, such as `i32`, you can work on a copy of the value to release the borrow on the `HashSet` early. To do this, you need to eliminate all borrows from the bindings in the `while let` expression. In your original code, `u` is of type `&i32`, and it keeps borrowing from `unprocessed` until the end of the loop. If we change the pattern to `Some(&u)`, then `u` is of type `i32`, which doesn't borrow from anything, so we're free to use `unprocessed` as we like.

```
fn herp(v: i32) {
    let mut unprocessed: HashSet<i32> = HashSet::new();
    unprocessed.insert(v);

    while let Some(&u) = unprocessed.iter().next() {
        derp(u, &mut unprocessed);
    }   
}
```

If the type is not `Copy` or is too expensive to copy/clone, you can wrap them in [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) or [`Arc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), and clone them as you iterate on them using [`cloned()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) (cloning an `Rc` or `Arc` doesn't clone the underlying value, it just clones the `Rc` pointer and increments the reference counter).

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn derp(v: &i32, unprocessed: &mut HashSet<Rc<i32>>) {
    if unprocessed.contains(v) {
        unprocessed.remove(v);
    }   
}

fn herp(v: Rc<i32>) {
    let mut unprocessed: HashSet<Rc<i32>> = HashSet::new();
    unprocessed.insert(v);

    while let Some(u) = unprocessed.iter().cloned().next() {
        // If you don't use u afterwards,
        // you could also pass if by value to derp.
        derp(&u, &mut unprocessed);
    }   
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
    herp(Rc::new(10));
}
```

Comment: If the type is not copyable, it might be easier to let the loop consume the set and let `derp` instead insert the items into a new `HashSet`

Comment: True, but that wouldn't work if `derp` uses the set for other purposes than removing the current item, e.g. if the processing of an item depends on what other items are left to process (the implementation of `derp` in the question is just for demonstration purposes, as I understand it).

Answer (score 18):

You have to think about what [`HashSet`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashSet.html) actually is. The [`IterMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/struct.IterMut.html) that you get from [`HashMap::iter_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.iter_mut) is only mutable on the value part: `(&key, &mut val)`, (`(&'a K, &'a mut V)`)

`HashSet` is basically a `HashMap<T, ()>`, so the actual values are the keys, and if you would modify the keys the hash of them would have to be updated or you get an invalid `HashMap`.

Comment: How would you suggest to replace a `HashSet` with another collection. I just need `contains`, `remove` and `insert`. A vector with a home-brew `contains`? And a way to `remove` a specific object, either by looking up its index or some other approach.

Comment: @FilipAllberg Can you give a code sample of what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Provided a condensed example in the original post